# Generating multiple versions of a document using a command inside \ifthenelse

Tags: ifthenelse

I'd like to be able to generate different versions of a document using some kind of print command inside an `\ifthenelse` statement. Here's an example of what I would like to do. I'd like to do it this way because my document is quite long and has many sections. I think it would be easier for me to do something like this rather than define all the text inside the `\ifthenelse` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\docVersion}[1]
{
% normally, text would go where the commands \printA{} and \printB{} would go
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{group A version}}{\printA{}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{group B version}}{\printB{}}{}
}

% so here, I could define that I want group A's version
\docVersion{group A version}

% and only this would be printed
\printA{Some stuff for group A here.}

% and this would not
\printB{Some stuff for group B here.}

% and this would be printed also
Some stuff for both groups here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are various ways [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1492/73317) (“Passing parameters to a document”). If true/false logic is enough, `\newif` can do (or `etoolbox`'s `\newboolean`, etc.). If you want a conditional with more than 2 outcomes, `\ifcase` could come in handy (or `expl3`'s `\str_case:nnTF`, etc.).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386307/73317) and [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500825/73317). Contrary to the above question, these are not focused on passing a parameter from the command line, which can be nice but is not part of your question.

Comment: The [docstrip package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) can be used for deriving/generating several different .tex-files from a common .tex-source by means of tags that get placed into the common source-file and that denote into which derived .tex-file a tagged snippet of code goes. Besides this, the answers to the question [Compile to PDF file with different name than the source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472944/118714) might be of interest to you.  My second answer to [shared common text across many documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451171/118714)  might be of interest, too.

Comment: In my answer to [Collection of redefined commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495883/118714) a list of resources with information about the packages docstrip and doc is provided. The answer to [Defining environment that can be turned on and off for different versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439249/118714) provides an example of how to derive a teacher's version and a student's version of a document from the same common .tex-input file.